# OSDM Parameters | Genesys Composer

Tags: voice-recognition, ivr, vxml, genesys

Hi i am Genesys composer 8.1.3..

I need to know the complete list of Nuance OSDM parameters like

```
1.noinput
2.nomatch
3.retry1
4.retry2
5.maximum attempts
6.grammar for both voice and dtmf..etc...,
```

which should be used by genesys composer 8.1.3..

When i googled about osdm , i got only visio site,which is shown below :

```
http://help.voxeo.com/go/vox/objectreference.osdm
```

Whether it holds good for genesys composer too?

Let me know..Thanks in adv.!

Answer (score 0):

Composer is probably not the limiting factor here, but rather your orchestration server/GVP/universal routing server. Which routing server would you like to create an application for?

For GVP you can find the list of supported tags here: http://genesyslab.info/repository/GVP/814_VXML_Help/voicexml_(vxml)_tags.htm